# How to redirect home page for website using Firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, redirect

I have a created website for example mysite.com and when i enter "mysite.com" url in browser as it redirects to "**mysite.com/index.php/home**" but I need to redirect it to "**mysite.com/index.php/home/**"

**Note:-** I just need to add "/" i tried changing url's in above code but not succeeded

This is my Index.html code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=index.php/home/index.html"><TITLE>Page has moved</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<A HREF="index.php/home.html "><h3> click here </h3></A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I finally found it using my domain url redirection and It can also be done this way !!!

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=index.php/home/">`